# Short Story. Super intelligent telepathic unborn child. Communicates telepathically with his mother. Writes a well received book

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A young married couple are expecting their first child. From the womb he communicates telepathically with his mother. He tells her to drink milk which she hates the taste of.

The unborn child tells them he is named Leonardo after Leonardo Da Vinci. He insists his mother read many high brow books including one in German since he wants to learn the language.

He writes a book by communicating telepathically with his mother who types it for him. Later on, he is able to control the typewriter by telekinesis.

I read since 2005. It seemed to have been written many years previously. The pregnant lady smokes which does not seem to trouble anyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *Special Delivery* by Damon Knight.

You can read it online [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/32011/pg32011-images.html).

> Moira had now decided that the baby was male, that his name was Leonardo (not referring to Len, but to da Vinci), that he had informed her of these things along with a good many others, that he was keeping her from her favorite foods and making her eat things she detested, like liver and tripe, and that she had to read books of his choice all day long in order to keep him from kicking.

Etc.